# Converting from GTK+ to Qt: menu structuring

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gtk, qt-designer

I'm trying to convert a Python application from GTK+ to Qt. In this initial phase, I don't want to change the internal workflow of the app so that I can keep the same structure. Keeping the same ergonomics means I must "translate" GUI management into equivalent terms or commands.

In the GTK app, menus are dynamically adapted to context: only the relevant items are shown. Non-relevant items are made invisible.

The app uses Glade for its GUI design, providing ui files. In this design, **all** items are present. When context changes, the menu data structure is scanned by a common function/method to find "annotated" items. The annotation gives the name of the valid context. If it is not equal to the new context, the menu item is made invisible. In the ui XML, this annotation is simply an attribute `groups="xxx"` in the `<item >` tag.

I could not find the equivalent feature in Qt. If it exists, I'd like to insert it with QtDesigner for ease of maintenance of the GUI.

Of course, this attribute must be queried by some widget method. Is this possible?

*Note: an alternate approach could be to create a submenu for each group and globally enable/disable the submenu. However, this will uselessly clutter the menu appearance because there are relatively few exclusive combinations (they can be displayed all within the height of the screen), this will complicate the menu structure (nested submenus) without real need and knowledge of the existence and name of the submenus would be required which defeats the goal of a generic function/method.*

Similarly, Glade has provisions to insert "placeholders" in menus which will be later dynamically replaced by menu items (again identified by an "annotation"). This allows for instance to add a list of plugins with a nested sub-menu.

How can I do that with Qt and QtDesigner?

Comment: Qt provides [QActionGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qactiongroup.html), but it's normally used for checkable items (exclusively or not) and not available in Designer. Besides, any object created in Designer supports dynamic properties (select the action from the object tree, press the "+" button) which allows setting arbitrary properties, you could then iter through the `actions()` of the menu and chek for `action.property("property_name")`, then set the visibility of the action accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about user properties. This seems promising. But I am in trouble to access menu items. I scan menus from the menubar (with `actions()` but menus are reported as `QAction`'s and I can't find a way to extract menu items from there.

Comment: Each submenu is represented by a QAction in the menu (or QMenuBar) that contains it. To access its menu, use [`action.menu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#menu).

Comment: Great, this works. Make your comment(s) an answer so that I can flag it as solution.

Comment: I'd like to, but I'd prefer to provide a comprehensive answer. I had some previous experience with Gtk with python a lot of time ago, so I don't really remember the way Glade treats menus: is that `groups` annotation considered standard or is it just a custom "property" you used for your needs? Not that it would change much, as I know that Gtk and Qt are quite different, but I'd like to be more aware of what I'm going to write, as I know that those differences require a lot of attention when switching frameworks.

Comment: Partially unrelated note: I don't know the reasons of your switch, but I generally sympathize. I started off on Python UI with PyQt, and initially found it a bit cumbersome (mostly due to my lack of experience). I almost immediately opted to Gtk as I found it "simpler" being a Linux user, but, after a while, I began to find out problems, inconsistencies and, most importantly, lack of *proper* support and documentation, including community response. My switch back to Qt was a total relieve, and [this](//youtu.be/gGZyVSOnqm0) will probably encourage you in case you were still in doubt as I was.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and encouragement. Regarding `groups`, I think after rereading the code that it is yet another custom annotation. But I think it is then used in a rather contorted way. Traditionally, this grouping is offered for radio buttons or check boxes in a specific set. Transposing the feature to sets of menu items is a bit abusing GTK API. It should be handled completely separate to provide a clean implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the powerful aspects of Qt is the [property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html), which allows to any QObject subclass to have properties that can be dynamic on every aspect, including their creation.

Most Qt objects have predefined properties (for instance, the [`text`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) property of a QLabel), but *any* property can be "created" for every QObject subclass, even if that subclass doesn't support it natively.

Qt Designer extends that feature by supporting adding custom "dynamic properties" to any object, and we can *bend* this aspect to our needs.

Using the [QStringList](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html) variant type, we can set a custom property that includes all menu "groups" in which each action would be shown, then we create a function that cycles through the given list of actions and creates a custom temporary menu, even recursively: menus are all composed of QActions, when a sub menu is present, that menu is accessible through the action [`menu()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html#menu).

In the following example I created a basic UI with a menu bar that contains three menus each one with their actions or submenus, some have a `menuGroups` property that indicates to which group the action or menu belongs. Then I added some widgets that have different combinations of `menuGroups`, to show how that would work.

Here is the python code:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

def getMenu(widget, actions=None, parentMenu=None, showTitles=True):
    if actions is None:
        actions = widget.actions()
    menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(parentMenu or widget)
    if showTitles:
        menu.setSeparatorsCollapsible(False)
    if not parentMenu:
        menu.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
    groups = set(widget.property('menuGroups') or [])
    for action in actions:
        if set(action.property('menuGroups') or []) & groups:
            if action.menu():
                menu.addSeparator()
            menu.addAction(action)
        elif action.menu():
            subMenu = action.menu()
            if set(subMenu.property('menuGroups') or []) & groups:
                if not parentMenu:
                    if showTitles:
                        menu.addSection(subMenu.title() or action.text())
                    else:
                        menu.addSeparator()
                    menu.addActions(subMenu.actions())
                else:
                    menu.addSeparator()
                    menu.addMenu(subMenu)
            else:
                subMenu = getMenu(widget, subMenu.actions(), menu, showTitles)
                if subMenu:
                    if not parentMenu:
                        if showTitles:
                            menu.addSection(action.text())
                        else:
                            menu.addSeparator()
                        menu.addActions(subMenu.actions())
                    else:
                        subMenu.setTitle(action.text())
                        menu.addMenu(subMenu)
    if menu.actions():
        return menu
    menu.deleteLater()


class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('menus.ui', self)

        for target in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QLabel):
            if target.property('menuGroups'):
                target.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.showContextMenu)

    def showContextMenu(self, pos):
        menu = getMenu(self.sender(), self.menuBar().actions())
        if menu:
            menu.exec(self.sender().mapToGlobal(pos))


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
test = Test()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

And this is the `menus.ui` file used above, open it in Designer and check the properties of menu items to understand it more:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>547</width>
    <height>403</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="fileLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>File</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>file</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="2">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="settingsLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>Settings</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>settings</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="viewLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>View</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>view</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="fileViewLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>File+View</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>file</string>
        <string>view</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="fileSettingsLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>File+Settings</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>file</string>
        <string>settings</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="2">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="viewSettingsLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>View+Settings</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>view</string>
        <string>settings</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0" colspan="3">
     <widget class="QLabel" name="fileViewSettingsLabel">
      <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
       <enum>Qt::CustomContextMenu</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="text">
       <string>File+View+Settings</string>
      </property>
      <property name="alignment">
       <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
      </property>
      <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
       <stringlist>
        <string>file</string>
        <string>view</string>
        <string>settings</string>
       </stringlist>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>547</width>
     <height>24</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuFile">
    <property name="title">
     <string>File</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QMenu" name="menuRecent">
     <property name="title">
      <string>Recent...</string>
     </property>
     <addaction name="recentFile1"/>
     <addaction name="recentFile2"/>
     <addaction name="recentFile3"/>
    </widget>
    <addaction name="actionOpen"/>
    <addaction name="actionSave"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="menuRecent"/>
    <addaction name="separator"/>
    <addaction name="actionQuit"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuView">
    <property name="title">
     <string>View</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionShowAll"/>
    <addaction name="actionShowNone"/>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuSettings">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Settings</string>
    </property>
    <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
     <stringlist>
      <string>settings</string>
     </stringlist>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionSettings"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuFile"/>
   <addaction name="menuView"/>
   <addaction name="menuSettings"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionOpen">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Open...</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>file</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSave">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Save...</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>file</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionQuit">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Quit</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionShowAll">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Show all</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>view</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionShowNone">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Show none</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>view</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="recentFile1">
   <property name="text">
    <string>File 1</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>file</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="recentFile2">
   <property name="text">
    <string>File 2</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>file</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="recentFile3">
   <property name="text">
    <string>File 3</string>
   </property>
   <property name="menuGroups" stdset="0">
    <stringlist>
     <string>file</string>
    </stringlist>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionSettings">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Show settings</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```